# Can not open ipynb file by double-clicking

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I used Python 3.8 and I used to open Jupyter Notebook double-click by nbopen.exe.
Then, I install some libraries such as pandas, numpy,... by Anaconda. I add the folder that has these libraries to the environment variables: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages'. After adding this, I can not open ipynb by double-clicking. I try to open it with jupyter-notebook.exe but it doesn't work.
How can solve this problem?

Comment: First of all, have you tried to remove the environment variable again to see if that has anything to do with the problem? What happens when you try to open the `.ipynb` inside of Jupyter itself?

Comment: It warned a traceback then it disappeared very quickly so I can not see what the traceback was.

Answer (score 0):

First, check

```
jupyter notebook --version
```

from your command prompt (Terminal, if you are a Linux user). If it gives a version, try opening from the command prompt itself by typing

```
jupyter notebook
```

in the command prompt. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but I try to open it by double - clicking.

Comment: @CuongTrinh checking the jupyter version will ensure that there has been no glitch in the notebook module.